# htaccess issue - strange [OR] behaviour

Tags: .htaccess

I've noticed an issue with [OR] in htaccess that I don't understand. What I want to do is redirect every non-existent file and every file that is a .php file (and not /index.php) to /404/. By my understanding following two blocks should do the same thing:

```
# .htaccess 1
RewriteEngine on

# cond 1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
# cond 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php$
# cond 3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
# rule 1
RewriteRule [^\.]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ /404/ [L]

# rule 2
RewriteRule ^(([^/\.]+)/?)*?$ /index.php [L]
```

and this:

```
# .htaccess 2
RewriteEngine on

# cond 1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# rule 1
RewriteRule [^\.]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ /404/ [L]

# cond 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php$
# cond 3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
# rule 2
RewriteRule [^\.]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ /404/ [L]

# rule 3
RewriteRule ^(([^/\.]+)/?)*?$ /index.php [L]
```

Yet, only the second block does what I want. The first .htaccess, for example - fails to redirect a non-existent file a.pdf and instead displays default server message about file not being found.

Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: For any URL with non-existent file, and, for example: `/a.pdf`

Comment: That's the issue - in my understanding both of these blocks should do the same. The behaviour however is correct in the second block

Comment: Please create index.php file with "A" in it. Use first .htaccess. For `/a.pdf` URL you'll get default "Not Found" server response. Use second .htaccess. You'll get "A" as `/a.pdf` will resolve to `/404/` which will get resolved to `/index.php`. Now - why are the behaviours not the same?

Comment: Because there are other rules in place and I want non-existent files and every php file to follow a known behavior which is already established.

Comment: Why? I'm providing the code to replicate the issue. All I'm asking is explanation why the behaviours are not the same.

Comment: I expect the behaviours to be the same and they're not - I'm asking why. If this is unclear after so many comments, then I'm truly at loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OR conditional in the first .htaccess is in the wrong order.

The `[OR]` flag creates a group around the two statements, effectively writing your conditional as:

```
if (
    (FILE_NOT_FOUND or FILE_NAME === 'index.php')
    and REQUEST_URI ends in .php
) { ... }
```

Written in this order, the conditional will never match a URI that ends in an extension *other* than PHP.

What you actually want is:

```
if (
    (FILE_NOT_FOUND or REQUEST_URI ends in .php)
    and FILE_NAME !== 'index.php'
) { ... }
```

Which can be expressed by simply rearranging the two related rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule [^\.]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ /404/ [L]
```

You can even catch your mistake by reading your own words (simplified to show the actual conditional you had in mind):

> What I want to do is **redirect every non-existent file** [or] **every .php file**, [and] **not /index.php** to /404/.

[Here is a good StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922399/how-to-use-and-or-for-rewritecond-on-apache) about the precedence of `[OR]` in .htaccess files if you'd like to learn more about how mod_rewrite actually works internally.

Comment: Thank you very much - I've looked at that answer before, but I guess it must have been late, or I was tired and the precedence of [OR] didn't register properly in my brain (and looking at it from standard language precedence point of view I was at loss on what's going on).